# using javascript var to query data with php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, onchange

i cant find any solution with this condition, when id user text value changed, name & address will filled. but it return some error in the php query.

sorry if this post duplicated because i cant find solution with my condition.

here the html form

```
    <form id="frm_add_bill" name="frm_add_bill" >

<label >id user</label>                                          
<input type="text" onchange="getplg()"  id="kdp" name="kdp">                    
<label >user name</label>

<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="name" id="name"  readonly>

<label >user address</label>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address"  readonly>
</form>
```

Here javascript and php code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  function getplg(){

                var kdpe = $('#kdp').value;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '',
                data: kdpe,
                timeout: 50000
            });

            }</script>

            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['kdpe'])) {

                $kpde=htmlspecialchars($_POST['kdpe']);


            $amxz=mysql_query("SELECT name, address from tbl_user where id_user='$kpde'");
            $camqz=mysql_fetch_array($amxz);

            echo "<script>document.write(fillem());</script>";

            }
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            function fillem(){

            document.frm_add_bill.name.value=<?php echo $camqz['0'];?>;
            document.frm_add_bill.address.value=<?php echo $camqz['1'];?>;

            }
            </script>
```

Comment: can you var_dump($_POST['kdpe']) and see the result?

Comment: and what is the use of getplg()

Comment: result from var_dump is empty..
im use getplg function to get value from id user and the value i will use for getting data from mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was found answer for this case

this js code use inside  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

         $("#kdp").blur(function() {


          var idkategori = $(this).val();
          if (idkategori != "")
          {

           $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"getsubkat.php",
            data:"id="+ idkategori,
            success: function(data){
             $("#name").html(data);
            }
           });
          }
         });
        });
        </script>
```

and this html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    User Code
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kpd" name="kdp"  >
  </div>
</div>
<div id="name">

</div>
```

and the php code are different page with js and html (getsubkat.php)

```
    <?php
include ("components/inc/connection.php");
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name, address from tbl_user where user_code='".$id."'");

 $data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo"<div class='form-group'>";
    echo"<label for='inputEmail3' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>user name </label>";
echo"<div class='col-sm-10'>";
    echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$data[user_name]'  readonly>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</div>";

echo"<div class='form-group'>";
    echo"<label for='inputEmail3' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>user address</label>";
echo"<div class='col-sm-10'>";
    echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$data[user_address]'  readonly>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getplg(){
        try{
            var kdpe = $('#kdp').val();
            console.log("here");
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: '',
                data: {val:kdpe}}).done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("hello");
            });
            }catch(Exception){
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

try this.

Comment: the alert didnt show,  no error but, name value and address value is empty

Comment: when i view source the error only this "Undefined variable: camqz" and inspect console no error

Comment: Edited the answer. Now check in the console what did you get.

Comment: and what about console.log(data) ?

Comment: console.log(data) not show anything is empty.. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all change your ajax function as:

```
function getplg()
{ 
    var kdpe = $('#kdp').val(); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'post', 
    url: '', 
    data: "kdpe="+kdpe, 
    timeout: 50000 
    }); 
}
```

Here you need to pass as `"kdpe="+kdpe` by using param.

And move `fillem()` in `if (isset($_POST['kdpe']))` check.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['kdpe'])) {
$kpde=htmlspecialchars($_POST['kdpe']);

$amxz=mysql_query("SELECT name, address from tbl_user where id_user='$kpde'");

$camqz=mysql_fetch_array($amxz);

echo "<script>document.write(fillem());</script>"; 
?>

<script>
function fillem(){
   document.frm_add_bill.name.value=<?php echo $camqz['0'];?>;
   document.frm_add_bill.address.value=<?php echo $camqz['1'];?>; 
}
</script>
<?php
} 
?>
```

**Side note:**

Stop using `mysql_*` becuase its deprecated and close in PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @srl `SELECT name, address from tbl_user where id_user='youVALUE'` RUN THIS QUERY IN PHPMYADMIN AND CHK getting results or not

Comment: it getting result 1 row,, and im try to echo $_POST['kpde'] it show empty :'(

Comment: Really sorry bro use this `var kdpe = $('#kdp').val();`  @srl... Also update in answer

Comment: no error in console, but when im look into view:source page, the php given error "Undefined variable: camqz"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104712/discussion-between-devpro-and-srl).

Answer (score 2):

You should pass data like this format:

```
$.ajax({name:value, name:value, ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `onkeydown`, `onkeyup`, `onpaste`, or `oninput` event instead of onchange event.